# If I want to remove catch(Throwable t) clauses from legacy code what should I look out for?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm

What kind of behavior is expected from the JVM/Tomcat, If I remove a catch like that? I'm interested in both Container and not Container managed Threads, the code is just an example. Can the side effects of not catching errors really hurt? The error of course are not handled properly inside catch clause.

> Example code:

```
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try{
        //Out of memory simulated
        int MAX = (int)Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int[][][] aryNumbers = new int[MAX][MAX][MAX];
        }catch (Throwable t){
            //OOM not handled here, just empty catch clause
            System.out.println("Out of Memory");
        }
        System.out.println("After Out of Memory");
        //other valuable instructions
    }
};
```

Comment: A lot, but one thing that super comes to mind: catching InterruptedException and swallowing it without re-setting the thread's interrupted flag.

Comment: Good point, it's a good improvement to add this to those clauses, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove a Catch like that, the running thread will be terminated due an uncaught exception. In your example, the Line `System.out.println("After Out of Memory");` would not be  printed at all.

If there are registered [UncaughtExceptionHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) they will be called.

In Tomcat, the User will get an Error-Page, depending what is configured in web.xml. If its the default error page, the full stack trace will be printed, which could present sensitive information.